# Replacing multiple json fields with the same name in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to modify a json file with partial success.

I have the same field names in different parts of this json file. For some reason my code only works on the second field. I don't know if there is a redundancy issue. My code is this:

```
with open(os.path.join(model_folder, 'config.json'), 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

config['speakers_file'] = os.path.join('model', 'speaker_ids', 'speakers.pth')
config['embeddings_file'] = [os.path.join('embeddings', 'corpus_speakers.pth'), os.path.join('embeddings', 'train_speakers.pth')]


with open(os.path.join(model_folder, 'config.json'), 'w') as f:
    json.dump(config, f, indent=4)
```

the config has the following lines which are filled automatically by the tool I am using:

```
    "speakers_file": "/home/username/pathinmymachine/modelrunfolder/speakers.pth",
    "embeddings_file": [
        "/home/username/pathinmymachine/corpusfolder/speakers.pth",
        "speakers.pth"
"speakers_file": "/home/username/pathinmymachine/modelrunfolder/speakers.pth",
"embeddings_file": [
    "/home/username/pathinmymachine/corpusfolder/speakers.pth",
    "speakers.pth"
```

I want to change them to:

```
    "speakers_file": "model/speaker_ids/speakers.pth",
    "embeddings_file": [
        "embeddings/corpus_speakers.pth",
        "embeddings/train_speakers.pth"
"speakers_file": "model/speaker_ids/speakers.pth",
"embeddings_file": [
    "embeddings/corpus_speakers.pth",
    "embeddings/train_speakers.pth"
```

But what I get is:

```
    "speakers_file": "/home/username/pathinmymachine/modelrunfolder/speakers.pth",
    "embeddings_file": [
        "/home/username/pathinmymachine/corpusfolder/speakers.pth",
        "speakers.pth"
"speakers_file": "model/speaker_ids/speakers.pth",
"embeddings_file": [
    "embeddings/corpus_speakers.pth",
    "embeddings/train_speakers.pth"
```

I am sure that i am missing something obvious but I think that it is mainly my ignorance as to how to read and write this to a json.

Comment: Is it possible to get a section of the data that internally json consistent? As it is now, just by what I see with indentation, your "first" speakers_file key looks to be nested under some other key but I can't tell as there is not enough to go on.

Comment: yes it is nested under "model_args"

Comment: ahhh... I can do this config['model_args']['speakers_file'], I just tried that and it worked. Your comment made more sense than you know. Now I feel super dumb. maybe you want to add it as a response and I will accept it :-)

Comment: Are you all set, or would you like an answer that recursively walks your config tree and replaces the value for all keys named speakers_file?

Comment: That would work too. i am good. i would like to give you credit for answering my question though

Comment: all good. I was not really a problem to begin with so there is no real answer :-)  I would just close/delete this.